# How do I alter the colors of a raster image with GIMP?

Tags: gimp, logo, color-conversion

I'm somewhat new to GIMP and I was hoping to take a logo like this:

[image: Logo on white]

And to change the colors of the background and font as someone did here:

[image: Logo on gray]

Except I'd like to do it with different colors.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a general solution (if more colors are involved) you could use the Color Exchange menu item to select the start colors and what color you would like them to end up.

For this particular case, which just has two colors, I would invert the image, and then use Hue-Saturation to adjust the color balance to go to blue.

[image]

(Your source image has a lot of compression artifacts which limits how much you can push things when adjusting).

Or you could threshold to make it black and white, then Invert, then Colorize, then adjust the brightness...

[image]